# Any computer can't run the app on any Android phone by USB cable

Tags: android, appcelerator

The new Appcelerator Studio can't run the app on Android device by USB cable.

The issue happens on each computer I tried, all those were Windows based. Doesn't matter what phone I plugged in by USB cable (LG, Samsung, HTC etc).

Everything was perfect and like a charm =) but the latest update of Appcelerator knocked me totally out... and I decided to ask Stackowerflow, believing in a miracle, after I spent last 5 days to figure this out...

The issue happens on any computer with any Android Device plugged in by USB cable.

It almost always throwing this:
  **Invalid "--device-id" value "LGD852ed33f0a"**

Sometimes, really rare, it's getting to the end when it tries to install an .apk to the phone, **but the same message appears** and it fails to install it, of course.

My environment is:

- Windows 7,8 or 10.
- Asus Laptops, Dell Desktops, etc.
- The latest release of Appcelerator downloaded from the official website.

[image]

Comment: If you run "appc ti info -t android" does it show that device ID for the connected devices?

Comment: Exactly, I figured the issue out by my own, by using this command a couple of days ago, and I got this working on Win10.
But still has the same issue on Win7... 

I posted a ticket to Jira Appcelerator here https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-521